# What do these characters inside the parentheses of a paremeter expansion (${(…)}) do?

Tags: zsh

hi am new to zsh and am trying to create multi-line prompt and came across this line of code:

```
    local pad=${(pl.$pad_len.. .)}
```

My 1st question is what is the `pl` inside the parentheses? Is it a command or operator or a flag(s)?

And my 2nd question is what are the dots that follow `$pad_len`?

Comment: Does my post answer your question? If so, please click the button to Accept it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Those are [Zsh parameter expansion flags](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags).

- `l.$pad_len.` makes the given (in this case, empty) string exactly `$pad_len` long, either by truncating it from the left or by padding it on the left with spaces.
- `l.$pad_len.. .` does the same as the above, but specifies explicitly to use the space character for padding — which is unnecessary, since the default is to pad with spaces.
- The `.`s here are arbitrary separators used to enclose each argument for the preceding flag. It doesn’t matter which (matching pair of) punctuation characters you use for this, as long they enclose each argument in pairs. So, `l:$pad_len:: :` and `l<$pad_len>< >` do the exact same thing.
- `p` makes `l` support [`print` escape codes](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-print) in the second argument — which is unnecessary, since we don’t use any here.

So, a shorter way to write this would be

```
local pad=${(l.$pad_len.)}
```

If you want to do this operation on a non-empty string, you can either pass the name of a variable

```
local foo=bar
local pad=${(l.$pad_len.)foo}
```

or pass a literal string with `:-`

```
local pad=${(l.$pad_len.):-bar}
```